# Connect two virtual machines together through the local network

Tags: networking, windows-xp, vmware, easyphp

I have installed Windows XP on two separate VMware Virtual Machines. I installed EasyPHP on the first VM and have set up a site. I want to view the hosted site on the second VM using a web browser.

How can I share a network between the VMs such that the hosted site can be viewed in this way?

Comment: It might be helpful to include what the host OS is for your virtual machines (IE: are you running Windows 10 on this PC?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have them on the same subnet, or have a routed path between the subnets they are on if they are different.  I'm more familiar with VirtualBox networking than VMWare, but a "bridged" type connection to your real network card should put them on your local, real LAN, they should get IPs from your dhcp server, etc.  An "internal only" or "host only" should let them see each other, and possibly your host machine as well.

Additionally, make sure the webserver  is listening on the LAN IP and not just `localhost`

Once all of this is done, then `http://ip.of.mach.ine1` should get you there, add a non-default port to the URL if needed.